# extract specific portion from text

Tags: python

Favorite I have

Following strings as input:

```
n [time%1:28:03::] [time] clock time
n [year%1:28:01::] [year] twelvemonth, yr
v [lily%1:20:00::] [lily] flower
v [man%1:05:01::] [man] homo, human being, human
a [government%1:14:00::] [government] authorities, regime
```

Expected output is:

```
[time] clock time
[year] twelvemonth, yr
[lily] flower
[man] homo, human being, human
[government] authorities, regime
```

I have tried out theses code for splitting and searching those text I need

```
def space_split(a):
    if a.count(" ") == 1:
        return a.split(" ")[0]
    else:
        return " ".join(a.split(" ", 2)[2:])


print(space_split("v [wind%2:35:00::] [wind] wind up, coil the spring of a mechanism"))
```

Output I get is:

```
[wind] wind up, coil the spring of a mechanism
```

Now how can I run these for multiple inputs? can any one help?

Comment: Is this input comes from a file ?

Comment: You seem to be getting the expected output. Where is the input coming from?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
for line in list_input.split('\n'):
    print(space_split(line))
```

If the input comes from a file:

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as your_file:
    for line in your_file.readlines():
        print(space_split(line))
```

For write these in a file:

```
with open('output_file', 'w') as your_file:
    for line in list_input.split('\n'):
        output_file.write(space_split(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: What if I want to save this to a file or write to a text file  in python

Comment: What is this list input , is this the list of data we printed previously?

Comment: @CyleySimon yes this is your multi-line text.

Comment: only last record is printed in the csv file ?

Comment: @CyleySimon do you know what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a way to create a partition instead of a split.
It should solve the problem of identifying the corresponding split to which you need to get it from.

```
def getPartitionResult(string_input):
    _, partition_parameter ,needed_result = string_input.rpartition("[")
   needed_result = partition_parameter + needed_result
   return needed_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_input = [
        "n [time%1:28:03::] [time] clock time",
        "n [year%1:28:01::] [year] twelvemonth, yr",
        "v [lily%1:20:00::] [lily] flower",
        "v [man%1:05:01::] [man] homo, human being, human",
        "a [government%1:14:00::] [government] authorities, regime"
        ]
    for input_arg in list_input:
        print getPartitionResult(input_arg)
```